# Why class C IP address has more networks than hosts?

Tags: ip-address, ipv4

In **IPv4** , class C has more than 2 million networks while it has only 256 hosts...I can't figure out the reason..?

Comment: While class-based network addresses are obsolete, it was a way to create a lot of small networks.

Comment: How can do so ?

Comment: Lets say you have a small network, perhaps something like ten or twenty hosts. Does it makes sense to use a network that allows for millions of hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So class based network addresses are obsolete. The reason Class C had so many network addresses and only 254 hosts addresses (its not 256, its 2^8-2) is because it was intended to be used by smaller organization that don't have a lot of hosts. If these organizations used, say, class B address, a lot of addresses would have been gone waste.

One must remember that the class based division was made at a time when networking was relatively new and no one was expecting number of hosts and networks to grow so big.

I'll give a better example. Say an organization has only 200 hosts. They could  get a class C address. Now, only 54 addresses are wasted. If they had to use a class B address, they would have got a lot of addresses that they would never use and would be wasted.

Comment: Thanks Arvind... got you ..but how is it 254.. could you explain that ?

Comment: The .255 is used as the broadcast address, anything addressed to that address should be answered by all devices in the same IP Block.
The .0 address is reserved as the network address and is not usable as a host address.

You could check this out: https://www.quora.com/How-many-IP-addresses-are-in-a-Class-C-IP-Block-24